# How to calculate set intersection of items between large number of users in a NoSQL database?

Tags: algorithm, firebase, data-structures, nosql, set

I am facing an efficiency problem trying to calculate set intersection of items between different users. Let's say that a user, called Bob, owns different items he would like to trade with other items other users own. Bob has an **inventory** and a **wishlist**. Now if Bob wants to obtain an item, say item **A**, from his **wishlist**, he should be able to view all users who have item **A** in their **inventory**. Logically, we should only display users who have item **A** in their inventory and at the same, have items in their **wishlist** that Bob has in his **inventory**.

My approach was to store, for each item in the **wishlist**, the users who have this item in their **inventory**.

This would be the structure in the database:

```
wishlist_items/
       itemA/
          user1
          user2
          user3
```

Next, to display relevant users (who have item **A** in their inventory and at the same, have items in their **wishlist** that Bob has in his **inventory**), I should fetch items in their **inventory** and perform a set intersection with the Bob's **wishlist**. Then sort the users by the highest number of common items between their **inventory** and Bob's **wishlist**.

I believe this approach should be feasible for limited number of users under **itemA**, however, it will prove extremely inefficient at scale especially when there are a lot of items as well.

Is there an efficient solution to solve this problem?

*Please note that I am currently using Firebase to store data and I am not opposed to using different technology stacks.*

Comment: The problem is not in the set intersection itself. What would be the case if the number of users under item **A** was exceedingly huge, say a million? We will then have to compute a million set intersection. I am trying to find a way to reduce the number of users to take into consideration.

Comment: Suppose bob wants item A, how about doing an intersection of set {Users that has item A} and set {User x that bob has items in x's wishlist}.
Both sets can be very large though.

Comment: That's my problem, how to efficiently find the second set?

Comment: It seems that you can query users that want item x. Can you do this query for every item that bob has and combine them?